# navagating while updating update-panel

Tags: asp.net

I have build an asp.net web site with 3 pages.
One of the pages has an update panel. It takes the server few seconds to update this panel.
When the client asks the server to update this panel, and tries to navigate to another page in my site at the same time - a problem occurs on FF only: the client cannot submit request to navigate to another page. Its request seems to be stuck (via firebug).

I googled and found that when a ajax request is invoked, the update panel is blocked and no other request to the server can be handeled. Is that so? Does someone can shed some light about the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding an UpdateProgress control that shows in a modal window isn't an acceptable approach?

Comment: You can have an idea of what I'm talking in the following link... http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx

Comment: Thanks everyone. At the bottom line it was a js some other programmer put and caused the error.

Comment: Another issue:
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An Unknown Error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0

My client is getting this exception. Does someone know what's the exact error means?

Comment: Probably best to ask this as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

This may be to do be firefox not being able to resolve the __doPostBack call correctly? When __doPostBack is called, if the script is unsuccessful in making the ajax call it falls back to a full post back of the client. Try looking into differencing of how firefox might handle this script call, not sure of the exact solution, but hope it helps.